# How to loop faster for bing number in iOS

Tags: ios, performance

I want to know is there any technique to loop faster on iOS like in this piece of code below

```
while (count < 1000000000) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {

        target = [[ballTargetArray objectAtIndex:j]integerValue];
        destination = [[ballDestinationArray objectAtIndex:j]integerValue];

        if (target != destination) {

            [ballPosition exchangeObjectAtIndex:(destination -1) withObjectAtIndex:(target-1)];
        }else{

            NSLog(@"same target and destination");
            return;
        }
    }
    count++;

    if (count %1000000 == 0) {
        printf("Round>>%d\n", count);// tracking
    }
}
```

Right now it take about 4-6 second per million count.
I just don't know where to start looking.

Thanks

Comment: I'd start looking in `//Do some stuff 16 time`, the loop looks fine in itself. Also, shouldn't `Instruments` be the place to look for that info?

Comment: Ok I will add what I do in code

Comment: Take the print out, skip every second item, that's about all we can offer so far

Comment: Use simple arrays. How does the exchange work?

Comment: @Wain Its the method for swapping elements in an NSMutableArray
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB)

Comment: Is ball position an array of ints too? If so, try using simple arrays for all. You must test with instruments to see what effect your changes have.

Comment: I would use C array instead of NSArray, that would bump speed, because accessing elements via '[[ballTargetArray objectAtIndex:j]integerValue]' pretty heavy, while using some 'int[10000] ballTargetArray;' will do the job faster because you can access elements directly by index.

Comment: @NSDmitry and Wain using C array greatly help the loop time Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no one give an acceptable answer I will just answer my own question that I find so far to close the question.
If anyone have better answer please don't hesitate.

As @Wain and @NSDmitry suggests to use simple C array when accessing he value by index

And I also try to optimize by doing for in for (just play around the for loop)
1000 * 1000 * 1000 = 1000000000

I can reduce the time from hour to less than 5 min when I doing this

```
    for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfOperation; j++) {
                    [ballPoaition exchangeObjectAtIndex:(destinationIntArr[j]-1) withObjectAtIndex:(targetIntArr[j]-1)];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Round>>%d\n", k * 1000000);
    }
```

If the large number is random between (10^1 - 10^9) I still have no idea how to do it

but anyway thanks for all suggestion